# How to run a shell command without forking

Tags: ruby, subprocess

I have a Ruby process that is consuming a lot of memory, and I want to run a shell command to find out how much memory my Ruby process is using. If I fork, all of that memory gets copied to the new process, and my box can't support this much memory usage. Is there any way to either:

1. Run the shell command without forking, or
2. Find out how much memory my process is using from Ruby?

Comment: Hey there, if you're downvoting, why not take a second and explain why? This sounds like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: Some people get a whole bag of downvotes and have to run off and use them up, not understanding that it costs them a point for each one they use. I think it's a good question so +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of forking, you may want to open up the file `/proc/PID/status`, where `PID` is the process ID of your process, the `$$` variable in Ruby, and read the line labelled `VmSize`:

```
File.open("/proc/#{$$}/status").each { |line|
    if line =~ /VmSize/
        puts line
    end
}
```

Running this in IRB gives me this:

```
irb(main):003:0> File.open("/proc/#{$$}/status").each { |line|
irb(main):004:1* if line =~ /VmSize/
irb(main):005:2> puts line
irb(main):006:2> end
irb(main):007:1> }
VmSize:   138972 kB
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed.